# Add to the end of a predetermined line using sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file in the format:

```
C 1 1 2
H 2 2 1
C 3 1 2
C 3 3 2
H 2 3 1
```

I need to add " f" to the end of specific lines, for example the third line, so the output would be:

```
C 1 1 2
H 2 2 1
C 3 1 2 f
C 3 3 2
H 2 3 1
```

From Googling, it seems that I need to use sed, but I couldn't find any examples on how to do specifically what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [this article on sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). Specifically, the section on [restricting to a line number](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-26). An example:

```
sed '3 s/$/f/' < yourFile
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Is there a way of doing it for multiple lines (eg lines 3 and 4) without doing this:

    sed '3 s/$/ f/' < yourFile > yourFile
    sed '4 s/$/ f/' < yourFile > yourFile

Comment: @ChrisSherer The very next entry on the sed page I linked shows ranges. `sed -i '3,4 s/$/ f/' < yourFile`. Also note the `-i` flag is necessary for in-place file changes. Otherwise you will need a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==3{$0=$0" f"}1' your_file
```